# Spark job with explicit setMaster("local"), passed to spark-submit with YARN

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a Spark job (2.2.0) compiled with `setMaster("local")` what will happen if I send that job with `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` ?

I tried this and it looked like the job did get packaged up and executed on the YARN cluster rather than locally.

What I'm not clear on:

- why does this work?  According to the docs, things that you set in `SparkConf` explicitly have precedence over things passed in from the command line or via `spark-submit` (see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).  Is this different because I'm using `SparkSession.getBuilder`?
- is there any less obvious impact of leaving `setMaster("local")` in code vs. removing it?  I'm wondering if what I'm seeing is something like the job running in local mode, within the cluster, rather than properly using cluster resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because submitting your application to Yarn happens before `SparkConf.setMaster`.

When you use `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`, Spark will run its main method in your local machine and upload the jar to run on Yarn. Yarn will allocate a container as the application master to run the Spark driver, a.k.a, your codes. `SparkConf.setMaster("local")` runs inside a Yarn container, and then it creates SparkContext running in the local mode, and doesn't use the Yarn cluster resources.

I recommend that not setting master in your codes. Just use the command line `--master` or the `MASTER` env to specify the Spark master.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for.  It sounds like this could cause confusion: if Spark is running in local mode, within the YARN application manager, it's not immediately obvious that it's local mode.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a Spark job (2.2.0) compiled with setMaster("local") what will happen if I send that job with spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster

`setMaster` has the highest priority and as such excludes other options.

My recommendation: Don't use this (unless you convince me I'm wrong - feel challenged :))

That's why I'm a strong advocate of using `spark-submit` early and often. It defaults to `local[*]` and does its job very well. It even got improved in the recent versions of Spark where it adds a nice-looking application name (aka `appName`) so you don't have to set it (or even...please don't...hardcore it).

Given we are in Spark 2.2 days with Spark SQL being the entry point to all the goodies in Spark, you should always start with `SparkSession` (and forget about `SparkConf` or `SparkContext` as too low-level).

---

The only reason I'm aware of when you could have `setMaster` in a Spark application is when you want to run the application inside your IDE (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA). Without `setMaster` you won't be able to run the application.

A workaround is to use `src/test/scala` for the sources (in sbt) and use a launcher with `setMaster` that will execute the main application.

Comment: Can provide an example of how to use launcher in src/test/scala?